# CUDA Illegal access to address strangeness

Tags: cuda, cuda-gdb

My question is: is the CUDA hardware faulty, or is there possibly another explanation?
I have a kernel which has been in use for about a year without modification.  Recently, I started getting segmentation faults at irregular intervals, i.e. it could be reproduced, sometimes after a few minutes, sometimes after hours of execution.  This led to a bare-minimum version of the program which still reproduced the segfault.  As well as much learning from stackoverflow posts.

cuda-memcheck, when run in a repeat bash loop, will eventually report:

```
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 4
=========     at 0x000048f0 in SegFault.cu:157:SegFault( float* )
=========     by thread (128,0,0) in block (3706,0,0)
=========     Address 0x003400e8 is out of bounds
```

The usual culprit of bad pointer operations was ruled out.  Another clue was the illegal addressing was not consistent in where it occurred in the code; it was occurring irregularly for any index to a global array, throughout the kernel.

At this point in my question, the most likely explanation is buggy code.  What leads me to believe the hardware is faulty comes from cuda-gdb:

```
cuda-gdb ./SegFaultTest
(cuda-gdb) set cuda memcheck on
(cuda-gdb) run
Illegal access to address (@global)0x245684 detected.

Program received signal CUDA_EXCEPTION_1, Lane Illegal Address.
[Switching focus to CUDA kernel 0, grid 1, block (5537,0,0), thread (0,0,0), device 0, sm 22, warp 28, lane 0]
0x00000000004f1ff8 in kernel( float * @global )<<<(33480,1,1),(512,1,1)>>> ( c=0x250000 ) at SegFault.cu:37
37              c[ix] += share_c[0];

(cuda-gdb) print &c[ix]
$2 = (@global float *) 0x255684
```

The index "ix" is:

```
int ix = blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y*gridDim.x;
```

And is not modified after instantiation.  Indeed, `0x245684` is below the starting address for `c=0x250000`.  Yet, when I query `print &c[ix]` it returns `0x255684`, which is an acceptable address for this array.  Reproducing takes 10-50 executions before it pops up again, **but the illegal address is always one bit `0x010000` different than what `print &c[ix]` returns.**  I can't explain the difference in address between the error message and print.  Combined with the one bit difference, I suspect faulty hardware.  FWIW, `0x010000` is equal to the maximum grid size for this Tesla C1060.

And finally, I replaced the CUDA card today with a new model.  I have not been able to reproduce after 100 executions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If cuda-gdb with memcheck enabled reports an illegal address access like:

```
Illegal access to address (@global)0x245684 detected.

Program received signal CUDA_EXCEPTION_1, Lane Illegal Address.
[Switching focus to CUDA kernel 0, grid 1, block (5537,0,0), thread (0,0,0), device 0, sm 22, warp 28, lane 0]
0x00000000004f1ff8 in kernel( float * @global )<<<(33480,1,1),(512,1,1)>>> ( c=0x250000 ) at SegFault.cu:37
37              c[ix] += share_c[0];
```

And querying that address returns a **different value**:

```
(cuda-gdb) print &c[ix]
$2 = (@global float *) 0x255684
```

Then the hardware is broken.

Comment: Another possibility is that the Cuda Toolkit version you are using has a bug. (See https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-exception-1-lane-illegal-address-but-size-was-allocated-with-malloc/24827/6)